# Is this a staircase number?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

## Challenge :

Check if the given number forms a `number staircase` or not

---

## Input :

A integer (greater than 0 and not decimal). NOTE : You can take input as string , array of digits.

---

## Output :

a truthy / falsy value depending on whether the number forms a staircase or not

---

## Number staircase :

A *number staircase* is an integer that , when read from left to right :

- Starts with 1
- which may be followed by 2
- which may be followed by 3
- and so on till `n`
- then the number descends starting at n - 1
- then n - 2
- then n - 3
- and so on till it reaches 1

### Note :

The *may be* part is used to indicate that if length > is greater than 1. If it is the order must be followed as is. i.e : 12321

---

## Example :

```
12321                          ---> true
12345654321                    ---> true
9                              ---> false
1                              ---> true
2                              ---> false
123421                         ---> false
112312318901323                ---> false
123456789101110987654321       ---> true
```

---

## Note :

The input given will always be an integer greater than 0 and will not be a decimal. Your output must be a `truthy or falsy` value depending on the input

---

## Restrictions :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes (for each programming language ) wins.

---

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits? Like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1,1,0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` for `123456789101110987654321`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder : I would rather prefer if you didn't but I guess you can

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the input?

Comment: @mypetlion : Not really , it is as high as your code can support (excluding hardcoded and purposedly low ones.) Normally the highest your language can support (but not in this case)

Comment: May we take a string of characters as input to a function? (or is this only acceptable input for a full-program?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan : You may take that as a function.

Comment: @JoKing : normally yes , but in this case I do since [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129340/staircase-numbers?rq=1) . Although it is different sadly the name is same so

Comment: @JoKing : Why not!

Comment: "and so on till it reaches 0" - should be "and so on till it reaches 1".

Comment: @djhurio : nice catch. Thanks.

Comment: [Very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100060/31716), nearly a dupe. It's slightly different, since this one allows the string to go above 9, but other than that they're the same.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 97 bytes

```r
function(n)"if"(n>1,{while({T=T+1;x=paste(c(1:T,T:2-1),collapse="");nchar(x)<nchar(n)})0;x==n},T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtbCoMwEEX/u4qSrxkaIZP61nQV2YAEg4KMopYK4tpTbX8O98C5c/D3Ogr@zW7tRwZG0XsB/CK5f7p@aGG3xj6o2szULGsLDqi00pY6IpRuHIZmWlojBFbsumaGDev/YDxQnTfDh7QYPBDePOgLpJ/6Z8UFcWqcpFlekCIiVeRZmsRnITB8AQ)

Takes `n` as a `character` or an `integer`; using `character` will give correct results for integers that can't be held precisely as a 64-bit `double`.

Generates staircase numbers until it finds one at least as long as `n` is, then tests for equality.

Equivalent to:

```r
function(n)
    if(n > 1){
        T <- T + 1
        x <- paste(c(1:T,T:2-1),collapse="")
        while(nchar(x) < nchar(n)){
            T <- T + 1
            x <- paste(c(1:T,T:2-1),collapse="")
        }
        return(x == n)
    } else
        return(TRUE)
```

Comment: Wouldn't replacing `function(n)` with `n=scan();` be shorter? (for integers of course)

Comment: @pajonk I suppose so. But I'll say I'm taking it as a string so this answer is correct for larger inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒḄ€Vċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7Wh41rQk70v3//39DI2MTUzNzC0tDA0NDQwNLC3MzUxNjI0MA)

Warning: Very slow (fast for `1` and `121`)! Prepend `DL` to make it faster.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>62</s> 57 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

Returns a boolean.

```javascript
f=(s,k=1)=>(m=s.match(`^${k}(.*)${k}$`))?f(m[1],k+1):s==k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ndBbC4IwFMDx9z6FiA9bmXq8L1h9kCgc5rrMSzjrJfrsS8GHQi1oHNjTjz/nXNidybQ@X5tlWR0ypThF0hQUMF2jgkqrYE16QsneeIgnsua4@40E4w1HxRZ2plgAXklKhUqrUlZ5ZuXVEXGkg@u5oGOsjT3b1pr6ls2Gxg/CwB@VE4ZMNXrDWS6HoR9oLOT@FWo3mjzDJGpVNzFxwHO9T/2tFIRRTMABAIfE0dsh@5XUCw)

#### How?

Starting with **k = 1**, we look for **k** at the beginning and at the end of the string, and recursively iterate the process on the remaining middle sub-string with **k + 1**. The recursion stops as soon as there's no match anymore. The input is a staircase number if the last sub-string is equal to **k**.

**Example for s = "1234321":**

```
 k | s         | match     | s == k 
---+-----------+-----------+--------
 1 | "1234321" | 1(23432)1 | no     
 2 | "2343"    | 2(343)2   | no     
 3 | "343"     | 3(4)3     | no     
 4 | "4"       | null      | yes
```

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBDYAgDADAbaAVJDJAXYT4IChRm6qxxPXx7sxf1vIeTxuve916rwTqmSLSDEIaJLeyAzsLYUDrGNEYSdNCpKaCpLh4dhF7/wE "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online"). Assume 0 as truthy and null as falsy (he didn't exactly specify did he)

Comment: Hum I didn't see that guess that's invalid. Sorry

Comment: @I'mnoone No worries! Interestingly, removing `m[0]==s&` instead would make it pass all test cases (but still fail on other ones such as `"123217"`).

Comment: ```f=(s,k=1)=>(m=s.match(`^${k}(.*)${k}$`))?f(m[1],k+1):s==k``` ?

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
/mjk+Sd_Stdl
```

Saved a byte thanks to RK.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Fmjk%2BSd_Stdl&input=%22123456789101110987654321%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
/mjk+Sd_Stdl
 m         lQ   For each d up to the length of the (implicit) input...
    +Sd_Std     ... get the list [1, 2, ..., d, d-1, ..., 1]...
  jk            ... concatenated.
/               Count how many times the input appears.
```

If you really want the input as an integer, you can use `}Qmsjk+Sd_Std` instead, but this is horrifyingly slow.

Comment: you can use `/` instead of `}Q` so it autocompletes `Q` at the end

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

<sub>-1 byte thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni?tab=profile)!</sub>

```hs
f x=elem x[read$[1..z]++[z-1,z-2..1]>>=show|z<-[1..x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsMgFAB/5Q0dWlKFZ9JNs3TuF4gUoS@NVE2IQkX67zYZjhsObrbpQ963NkFR5ClA0RvZ10kj59V0na4Mr5UJztGMo0rz8v1VyY5cjGnBuggKgl0fTzivm4sZOEw7x@Wy27tICZSU8KZ8X2KmmFND0Q@3oRf4Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n=1,t='1',u='':t+':'>s>t<s*f(s,n+1,t+`n+1`,`n`+u)or s==t+u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7RCoMwDHyeX5EXia4dmKrTyuq31DFkwlbF1od9fVcnyiAkd7njuOnjnqMR3vfq1b3vjw4sN4q4U0jIF4XYOIYNtrZ1N3vukyCzIDMdjubaaLak4wxWKccW368QBgNJdEISuQghGyrKa1nsXG7f3xaHYzcHvE4tM8pF/hdQ1ZIyIspkXR1paROdpnkwDjAWhYVLC7FFiCFUhdA3Tf0X)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>138</s> <s>107</s> 102 bytes

```cs
bool t(List<int>s)=>s.Select((j,i)=>s[0]==1&&s.Last()==1&&(i==0||j+1==s[i-1]||j-1==s[i-1])).All(x=>x);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZA9D4IwEIZ3f0Un08ZCKKBIsCTGlc3BgTAo6VDStInXRBLxt2PBSBzB4e7yJPe@91GDV4Ps@5sxCllcSLAHqW0OhOfgn4UStcW4oXLgMqg4Z@s1@MUVLCYjYMl50HXNhnEOpfRY5cCbgBD/qBRued6SrD8ZDUYJ/3KXVhRSC2yxFg80zUVPxGhIIxcMvQjJVvMlMd3SnYt4qTxdMGl@a7h8f7f1As1H9c17mtLA1eH26K/PJaMHcyZsyKnD5Pehg2n/Bg)

Explanation:

```cs
bool t(List<int>s)=>
    s.Select((j,i) =>         //iterate over each item and store the return value
        s[0]==1&&s.Last()==1  //does the sequence start and end with 1?
        &&                    //AND
        (i==0                 //is it the first item?
        ||                    //OR
        j+1==s[i-1]           //is the item 1 greater than the previous?
        ||                    //OR
        j-1==s[i-1])          //is the item 1 smaller than the previous?
    ).All(x=>x);              //did all pass the criteria?
```

Comment: Actually, the `Zip...Skip` method in my previous comment fails on `[1,1]`, which should return `true` if I understand the spec. I've deleted it.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I've never utilized Zip before, but I see now how it can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
L€L€ûJså
```

Warning: EXTREMELY SLOW! Add `g` to the start to speed it up.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/3edR0xoQPrzbq/jw0v//DY2MjQwB)

Explanation:

```
L           1..input
 €L         for each element, map to 1..element 
   €û       palindromize each element
     J      join each element from a list to a string
      så    is the input in that list?
```

Old Explanation:

```
F           For [0 .. input] map over
 NL          Push 1..i
   û         Palindromize
    J        Join
     ¹       First input
      Q      Equal?
       }   end loop
        O  Sum.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzc/n8G6vQzsDa/3//zc0MgQA)

Comment: Palindromize ? What does this do? Because as you may know the stairs with 10+ are no palindromes

Comment: @YassinHajaj It palindromises the array, not the string

Comment: Alright thanks for the info

Comment: @YassinHajaj `gLη€ûJså` is another, where you can see the vectorization of the palindromization using `€û` palindromize each.

Comment: @okx `gLη€ûJså` for an 8-byte that doesn't blow up TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 77 bytes

```python
lambda s,r=range:s in[''.join(map(str,r(1,k+2)+r(k,0,-1)))for k in r(len(s))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vco7EsIgEADQ3lPQsTtBhyV/Z3IStcAxUSQhzELj6dHWV7/4ya89mLJM17La7f6wIime2IbnfE7ChYuUp/fuAmw2QsqsGEj5ymDF4JVWR0LEZWfhf1kwrHOAhHgrkV3IYgFJpm7arh9G0kSkx6Hv2qY2JPHwfySWLw)

Comment: Save four by accepting an integer if we may error once we hit longs: [TIO](https://tio.run/##HYvBDoIwEETP@hW9tRsWQ5eTJPgjakKNoGtkS5Ze/PpKOcxM3mRm@aV3FMpTf8vfMD@ewTBqr0FeYzfwwHK19vSJLG4Oi1uTojqPUhFU6gQbrD0ATFGNGBajjuGeC6ZxTaXZ1oQtntE36D16Qiq@wZ60qSXojodFWdJ@Q2Pri0UzuUKQ/w). We'd need quite some time and memory by that point anyway!

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), <s>57</s> <s>55</s> 46 bytes

```
{GenerateFirst[N@Join@Bounce@1&`:,`>=:`#&_]=_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUtNC4IwGL73KwaFpx18p6YTDCko6CAduo3hhr6WlylunaLfvkwJHni@tXO6eaLvSF749wUNTtrhuZ@sE1V5HXpTHoeXabCEQOVUHYpcbYNaFvXHV4itFbtxbB5yc5t64@5o3UlbtKKjRACLGFAyU5zsk3gxfPaUsDVd2ln8kPEQIhb952nGIQSAkGfp@pXSfwE) Ah, that's much more elegant.

With `Generate` (49 bytes):

```
{g@Generate[{g@_>=#_2}&_]=_}g:=N@Join@Bounce@1&`:
```

### Explanation

```
{GenerateFirst[N@Join@Bounce@1&`:,`>=:`#&_]=_}
{                                            }   anonymous lambda, argument: _
 GenerateFirst[                  ,        ]      find the first element satisfying...
               N@Join@Bounce@1&`:                    this generation function
                                  `>=:`#&_           and this condition
                                           =_    is it equal to the input?
```

The generation function simply creates the `N`th staircase number. Then, this search terminates once `` `>=:`#&_ `` is satisfied. Expanded, this is:

```
 `>=:`#&_
 (`>= : `#) & _      NB. remember _ is the input
                     NB. also, f:g is f[...Map[g, args]]
 { #_1 >= #_2 } & _
 { Size[_1] >= Size[_2] } & _
 { Size[_1] >= Size[the original input] }
 [n] -> { Size[n] >= Size[input] }
```

So, this terminates once the length of the generation function's output is at least that of the inputs. Thus, this generates the smallest staircase number at least as long as the input number. Thus, if the input is a staircase number, the result will be the same staircase number, and otherwise the next longest staircase number. As such, a simple check with equality to the original input is sufficient for determining whether or not it was a staircase number.

### Attache, 55 bytes

```
0&{If[#_2>#g[_],$[_+1,_2],_2=g!_]}g:=N@Join@Bounce@1&`:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUs9D4IwFNz9FTUQFjv0FRBKgiE66UAc3JqmECyVBYitk/G31woxucu7j3ettW33UK5HRelI9D73PJD0EGguBQ653AGWVHiWeivFRxdlXV2mYayO02vsVAVRU7haqbvh4Tx3Wmyuz2G0N2XsqTXK8B4jDjSmgJE/SbpPk8Uw7zGia7q0XvyQMwIxjf/vWc6AAABhebZuhXBf) With plan ol' recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç╗☻W╧ΩÆΘαφ←≤─♣
```

[Run and debug it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#p=80bb0257cfea92e9e0ed1bf3c405&i=12321)

Very slow for bigger numbers.

Comment: [9 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=92a194c34bd46ee309&i=12345654321)

Comment: Slight change for [7 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82cea998253bfd&i=121)

Comment: And a fast one at [8 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e2f7a8dcb8a7d41c&i=123456789101110987654321&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
1#.[:(<-:"_1<@([:;>:<@":@-|@i:)@<:@#\)":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCoJAFEX3fsVjXIxCIz7HSX1N8SBw1aqtQkQ4VAQt2hT079OAYJGLC4fLvefqRSYdrAkkLCAHClEZbPe71mOcdZRYReKAlpOOVhuyLIjVmy@UsiWO@1SQTyOIhtP5Dg5wguIHdWmWptT/VVU3mCOGqcYSTYgOjJg3dTXun@NBtsfbY3jJ732iYJpbZwIHgQvtPw)

I'm not quite happy with this soluiton - a lot of `@` and boxing `<` .

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 109 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
	X =L ='1'
C	R =LT(SIZE(L R),SIZE(N)) X R	:F(O)
	X =X + 1
	L =L X	:(C)
O	OUTPUT =IDENT(L R,N) 1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoAgFADn51e8LR@1CE2CUxkI8gwzkMbmqKH/x8zthrt77@d8rrEUYDSO1z0JyGg8mk51YoJYOcnNHVZ6jDQ0YiLMGEEvMlDzM/aoBPi/zKDlRCJA2FP91e1sOf35wFQty3Mp6gM)

Curiously, replacing `'1'` in the second line with `1` causes the program to fail on the input of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 36 bytes

```
{|/($x)~/:{,/$(1+!x),1+1_|!x}'1+!#x}
```

Takes a string such as "12321" as a parameter.

This function is written as a long chain of function applications, as in `f g h x`, so read the commented versions from the bottom, going up.
`{x+1}` is `lambda x: x+1`, x is a default param name. Check out https://pastebin.com/cRwXJn7Z or the interpreter's help for operator meanings.

We generate the staircase number with `n` in the middle by `{,/$(1+!x),1+1_|!x}`:

```
{,/                      / join all the chars
   $                     / tostring each number
     (1+!x)              / take the range [0..x-1]; add 1 to each
            ,            / concat
             (1+1_|!x)}  / take the range [0..x-1]; reverse it; drop 1; add 1 to each
```

The whole function `{|/($x)~/:{,/$(1+!x),1+1_|!x}'1+!#x}`:

```
{|/                                   / any_is_true
   ($x)~/:                            / match the string with each of the generated staircases
          {,/$(1+!x),1+1_|!x}'        / make staircase number of each of the numbers
                                      / (note: the x in the inner lambda shadows the outer x)
                              1+!#x}  / take the range [1..length of the string, inclusive]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 11 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```
Êõõ mê m¬øU
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=yvX1IG3qIG2s+FU=&input=IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEwMTExMDk4NzY1NDMyMSI=)

---

### Explanation

```
                :Implicit input of string U
Ê               :Length of U
 õ              :Range [1,Ê]
  õ             :Range [1,el] for each element
    mê          :Map & palidromise
       m¬       :Map & join
         øU     :Contains U?
```

---

### Alternative, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

This solution, which can take input as a string or an integer, will return an array of numbers for truthy or, eventually, throw an error for falsey, if it doesn't cripple your browser before that. Use with caution.

```
@¥Xê q}aõ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=QKVY6iBxfWH1&input=IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEwMTExMDk4NzY1NDMyMSI=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

<sup>-6 thanks to @BMO!</sup>

```hs
elem.show<*>(`take`[[1..n]++[n-1,n-2..1]>>=show|n<-[1..]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtNDoMgGESvQkwXWn4iqF0Jl@iSkMgCoxE/m4IpC@9OSzeTmbw3iw2b8z7nWTrvdhaW4zPeVT1Fu7lJa84YGIw1UE6ACsa4UUoW64KRFmxMk3e7ApLodcZnfN9O8Cu4oIuFEsYVkgpVGJddzyg1V/pdW8IJF534Zz88hr70ruXG5C8)

Comment: Theoretically works for `12345678910987654321`, if you are able to construct a list with that many elements.

Comment: @BMO I knew there had to be a way to do that. Thanks

Comment: @BMO [Your golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163839/61384) is really obvious in hindsight...

Comment: It's also very close, I would have suggested it as an improvement if I didn't already post it (I didn't see yours until I posted mine).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lp`, 49 bytes

```perl
$i++while s/^$i//;$i-=2;$i--while s/^$i//;$_||=$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtLDsIgFEXnrKKJzBqER6GfNCzBLWhMRH0JUlJoOunaRawzJyc59@QGOzudM8W6Xp/obBX5mSLnI0Vm5Jfsb79sm6GYSzKLv9n7eLg6N62xSjYm9I/qtbiEoVysTzPamEE2SrddP4AAADH0XatVI4GU8KPaXZCBFOy@D@8pJJx8zOykjwJEZi58AA)

`0` = truthy, anything else = falsy

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
$
;1
+`^(.+)(.*)\1;\1$
$2;$.(_$1*
^(.+);\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUtJCoAwELvPO0ZoFUozdWnpA/yEaD148OJB/H@1KoQkZDm3az9W5EqNKTNFUJNmZRqtTK0nxAlMLJGNWhg1vVUJc4Y4AT3cdn3XFh8IJG9SikcLfLBw4v7h4AMsABv88L1u) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Leo. Explanation:

```
$
;1
```

Initialise `n` to `1`.

```
+`^(.+)(.*)\1;\1$
```

While `s` begins and ends with `n`:

```
$2;$.(_$1*
```

Delete `n` from the ends of `s` and increment `n`.

```
^(.+);\1$
```

Test whether `n` is left.

Comment: I think your `\d`s can become `.` and save you two bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 142 bytes

```java
s->{int n=1,l,f=1;try{for(;;s=s.substring(l=(n+++"").length(),s.length()-l))if(!s.matches(n+".*"+n)&!s.equals(n+""))f=0;}finally{return f>0;}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lZCxbsIwEIZ3nuKaobIbMHGAQhqFsVtZYKs6mOBAqOPQ2KGKojx7egTUoQupdJZ85//O/3dHcRaj4@6zjZUwBt5EqusBQKqtLBIRS1hdUoBtnispNMRkbYtU78HQEB8aPBjGCpvGsAINEbRmtKxxAOiID9UwiXhoi6pO8oKEoYkMM@XWdEOIioh2XddxKFNS7@2B0KH5vY4UpWlCHgzLhI0P0qDYYU@Oq@kjFuVXKVRXcyhNIi9sklQLpaq6kLYsNCRLrDVtePV4KrcKPd6snvN0BxnS3njePwS9kl5WABlyaPndJaQjBRiPYVOU9lC9dOm6MlZmLC8tO@EEqzTJmGYxcTj6Ce9p/InfUzedPc@m/1HPFwH3OOdesJj/aUWGV1yavMvg9/gt6Omon3VUXmIReHziT3p13ETNoGl/AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                 // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  int n=1,           //  Stair integer, starting at 1
      l,             //  Length integer to reduce bytes
      f=1;           //  Result-flag, starting at 1
  try{for(;;         //  Loop until an error occurs
          s=s.substring(l=(n+++"").length(),s.length()-l))
                     //    After every iteration: remove `n` from the sides of the String
        if(!s.matches(n+".*"+n)
                     //   If the current String with the current `n` isn't a stair
           &!s.equals(n+""))
                     //   And they are also not equal (for the middle)
          f=0;       //    Set the flag to 0
   }finally{         //  After the error (StringOutOfBoundsException) occurred:
      return f>0;}}  //   Return whether the flag is still 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Regex (PCRE)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), 92 bytes

```
^(1|\d(?=1|9)|[2-79](?=8)|[2-68](?=7)|[2-57](?=6)|[2346](?=5)|[235](?=4)|[24](?=3)|3(?=2))+$
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/F9j2El/5)

I'm open to any suggestions to improve this.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to following users:

```
@Nooneishere
@LyricLy
@JoKing
```

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 147 bytes

```python
g=s=input()
f=1
o='1'==s[0]
while`f`==s[0]:s=s[len(`f`):];f+=1
f-=2
o&=`f`==s[0]
while s and`f`==s[0]:s=s[len(`f`):];f-=1
o&=f==0
o|=g=='1'
print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1NCoMwGET33ymyMkoRTPytZU5SBAs1GpAkNJZS6N3TiNBdV8MM7zHuvS3WyBBmeGjjnluakYIgCy444K/FQK9Fr9OoxqP2PsY6mTQuWT9c1CniKockm@BHHRLz7Gbu/9V8f0qggILsBzP2V3IPbTZmQ@BCllXdtN25a5u6KqXgXw)

Comment: The output doesn't have to be the strings `true` and `false` but truthy and falsey values. `1` and `0` would work for example

Comment: @dylnan : I just read that , thanks. Still golfing (a lot to go)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `s[0]` instead of `startswith`? Errors are allowed, and you can say 'outputs 1 for staircase, anything else (including nothing) [since stderrr is ignored] for non-staircase'.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere : good idea. apparently coding while sleeping is not such a good idea thanks

Comment: You can save bytes by replacing the `if x:o=0` statements with `o*=x`.

Comment: This doesn't work without a trailing character for truthy inputs

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##dY1NCoMwGET33ymyMkoRTPytZU5SBAs1GpAkNJZS6N3TiNBdV8MM7zHuvS3WyBBmeGjjnluakYIgCy444K/FQK9Fr9OoxqP2PsY6mTQuWT9c1CniKockm@BHHRLz7Gbu/9V8f0qggILsBzP2V3IPbTZmQ@BCllXdtN25a5u6KqXgXw) fixes most of your issues, but still doesn't support staircase numbers above n=9

Comment: Your 138 byte solution always returns False, since `g` is never 1. You should probably *test* these solutions before posting them...